# PHP modify file: File is not modified, but no error messages printed to console

Tags: php, fwrite

I have been searching the net for a while, but I really cannot find anything helpful. I cannot find the errors in my code and I'm not getting any in the console. I can open my file, I change it's string and I don't get any errors writing to it, but the file does not get modified. What am I missing?

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/wsplaetze.OLD.txt";
$newline = "";
$handle = fopen($file, "r+");
$counter = 0;
if($handle) {
    while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        ++$counter;
        $parts = explode(' ', $line);
        $to_add = $parts[0] . " " . intval($parts[1]) . '\n';
        foreach($ws_array as $ws) {
            if($parts[0] == $ws) {
                $anzahl = intval($parts[1])-1;
                $to_add = $parts[0] . " " .  $anzahl . '\n';
            }
        }
        $newline .= $to_add;
    }

} else {
    debug_to_console(error_get_last()."ERROR");
}

debug_to_console("length ".$counter);
debug_to_console($newline);

if(!fwrite($handle, $newline)) {
    debug_to_console("Error writing to file:  ".$file);
} else {
    debug_to_console("Great! Everything is fine! This is the file you wrote to: ".$file);
}
fclose($handle);
```

The file itself consists of ids and numbers associated with it, split by whitespaces, like this:

```
ab 12
abs 23
skd 12
```

etc.

What am I doing wrong? I really don't know where to look anymore, as I am not getting any of the error messages above!
I can read the file (correctly!), so the file name seems to be write as well? But then again, nothing changes.. I am really confused!

EDIT: Using the help in the comments, the code works now!! The file has to be re-opened! That way the old content is overwritten! I changed it to this:

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."files/wsplaetze.OLD.txt";
$newline = "";
  $handle = fopen($file, "r+");
  $counter = 0;
        if($handle) {
            while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                ++$counter;
                $parts = explode(' ', $line);
                $to_add = $parts[0] . " " . intval($parts[1]) . "\n";
                foreach($ws_array as $ws) {
                    if($parts[0] == $ws) {
                        $anzahl = intval($parts[1])-1;
                        $to_add = $parts[0] . " " .  $anzahl . "\n";
                    }
                }
                $newline .= $to_add;
            }
    fclose($handle);

        } else {
            debug_to_console(error_get_last()."ERROR");
        }


    $filew = fopen($file, "w");
    if($filew) {
        fwrite($filew, $newline);
    }
    fclose($filew);
```

Comment: plus `'\n';` needs to be double quotes `"\n";`

Comment: I tried your script and it works for me. BTW, you should put the `fwrite` code inside the `if ($handle)`, otherwise you'll try to write to the file when opening it failed.

Comment: Note that your script doesn't overwrite the original file contents, it appends the new version at the end of the file. So if the file is originally 3 lines, it will be 6 lines when the script is finished.

Comment: Why does it append? I thought thats why I had to use "r+" instead of "a". How can I change the file, if not like this?

Comment: Okay, I had to reopen FileZilla, for some reason it never showed that the file was indeed modified (the string was added). Now if I use "w" or "w+" as suggested, I get an error and my file is empty afterwards.

Comment: "r+" really just appends the new data to my file. But that is not what I want to do! I read that "r" is for reading and "r+" for reading and writing, so I figured it would be overwriting, but it obviously isn't. What is, then? "a" doesn't work either!

Comment: Okay!! This is now working! It seems that I have to open the file twice! Once for reading it (using "r+") and once for writing to it (using "w")! I don't know if there is an easier solution, but it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have already stored the content you want to write to the file into the $content variable.

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/wsplaetze.OLD.txt";

// @ prevents errors but allows the function to return true or false

if(@file_put_contents($file, $content, LOCK_EX)){
    debug_to_console("Great! Everything is fine! This is the file you wrote to: ".$file);
}else{
    debug_to_console("Error writing to file:  ".$file);
}
```

Comment: Usually LOCK_EX is not needed but it prevents concurrency issues